# PrimeNG Table Responsive Customization

Tags: primeng, primeng-turbotable

PrimeNG Table responsiveness have a default look and feel of stacking or prioritising. Any idea if it is possible to customize the stacking look and feel with other template ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by other template ? You can use it with the theme you prefer. Do you want to add custom CSS ?

Comment: I want to have custom formatting of the responsive look instead of the plain field and value look in their sample page. https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/responsive

Answer (score 1):

it's possible. I've made in one page. I subscribe some classes on the break point. Ex:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 70em) {
    .mv-text-container{
     white-space: normal !important;
     text-overflow: initial !important;
     overflow: auto !important;
   }

   .ui-table table {
     width: 99%;
   }

  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-thead > tr > th,
  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-tfoot > tr > td {
     display: none !important;
  }

  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-tbody > tr > td {
    text-align: left !important;
    display: block !important;
    border: 0 none !important;
    width: 100% !important;
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box !important;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box !important;
    box-sizing: border-box !important;
    float: left !important;
    clear: left !important;
  }

  .ui-table-responsive .ui-table-tbody > tr > td .ui-column-title {
    padding: .4em !important;
    min-width: 30% !important;
    display: inline-block !important;
    margin: -.4em 1em -.4em -.4em !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
  }


  tr > td {
    text-align: left !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    padding-left: 15px !important;
  }

  tr > th > {
    border: 0px !important;
    text-align: left !important;
  }

  tr {
   border: 1px solid #D5D5D5 !important;
  }

  tr > td:last-child {
   padding-bottom: 15px !important;
   margin-bottom: 0 !important;
  }

  tr > td:first-child {
   padding-top: 15px !important;
  }
}
```

But you've to make in style.css (src/styles.css) or, if you want to alter css in just on component you've to disable encapsulation like this:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-flex-novo',
   templateUrl: './flex-novo.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./flex-novo.component.css'],
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```